# Error when renaming eithernet device: 'Error either dev is a duplicate or "enp96s0f0" is a garbage'

Tags: networking, centos

I received these new computers that use the "eno" network naming convention. But the application I am working with was expecting the "enp96s0f0" naming convention. I am trying to rename the ports but am getting this error:

```
Error either dev is a duplicate or "enp96s0f0" is a garbage
```

The way I am going about it is adding "net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub. After updating grub and rebooting the network ports come up with the "eth" naming convention. Then I try to do this:

```
ip link set eth0 down
ip link set eth0 enp96s0f0
```

And I get the error. How can I get around this?

Comment: The convention is the same. `eno*` devices are attached to the motherboard, while `enp` devices are generally on an expansion card in a PCI* slot. I wouldn't bother renaming them; this will just cause you lots of grief later. (And even now.) Fix the application configuration instead.

Comment: The thing is, the older versions of these computers had the "enp" naming convention on the motherboard. So that confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. All I wanted to do was change the name. I needed to use this syntax:

```
ip link set eth0 name enp96s0f0
```